# How to pass variable from event method?

Tags: c#, variables, events, methods

I have a event method
`private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)`
with some code in it. There I want to use a variable from another event method called
`public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

so if a user writes a number it gets saved in a variable in the second method and i want to use this variable in the first method where a button gets clicked. How do I pass it?

Comment: Declare it at the class level?

Comment: that was fast. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a field of your form class. You can then write it in one event handler and read it in another:

```
public partial class MyForm
{
    private string _someValue = null;

    public void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _someValue = "Some New Value";
    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_someValue != null)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }   
}
```

Though perhaps you can just read `TextBox2.Text` in the second method.